# Connect Four game - understanding how array keeps always the same length

Tags: javascript

I'm a self learner, please bear with me.
So I'm following this tutorial on how to code a connect4 game and there's two things I'm definitely not getting

1 - every time I click on a cell I call the changeColor() and push to an empty array that specific cell. I dont get how the array always keeps only one cell.. it always has same length. Shouldn't it be adding each cell I click on to the array?

2 - in the stylesheet I defined that every cell would have the background color of white and when applying a if/ else condition as "if the cell is white then do something" the person in the tutorial defined in the js file once again that each cell has to have the background color of white in order for this condition to work 
This does not make much sense to me because if its already defined in the stylesheet why does it not work unless I define it again in the js file?

Any help is much appreciated :)
codepen : https://codepen.io/mullerz/pen/WNremXo?editors=1111

```js
tableCell.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

    el.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
})

function changeColor(e){
    let column = e.target.cellIndex; 
    let row = [];
    for(let i = tableRow.length-1 ; i > -1; i--){ 

        if (tableRow[i].children[column].style.backgroundColor == 'white'){       
          row.push(tableRow[i].children[column])

          console.log(row)

            if (currentPlayer === 1){
                row[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';   
                playerTurn.style.color = player1Color;       
                return currentPlayer = 2;
            }
            else{
                row[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';      
                playerTurn.style.color = player2Color;            
                return currentPlayer = 1;
            }    
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Variables in JavaScript are scoped. You are defining `let row = []` every time the functions is called thats why the array is always empty at the start.
   If you would move the variable declaration outside the function block it would not be redeclared everytime the function is run.
2. Because of `if (tableRow[i].children[column].style.backgroundColor == 'white')`
   It seems to me the background color is used to check if the field was not selected before. But this is a bad practice and shouldnt be done.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 2.

A cell has the class `slot`, which sets the background colour to white, but the element itself also has a style object as a property, but this object has nothing set.

When rendering the style, the browser does so from broadest to narrowest (then `!important` things). Style classes are broader than style applied directly to an element. For example if you have this css:

```css
.notred
{
  color: black;
}
```

And this element:

```html
<p style="color:red" class="notred">this text would be red</p>
```

The element's text will be red, despite the class saying it should be black.

Your code is using a check on the element's style property to make sure the cell is empty, so it has to set the style property otherwise the value is an empty string. In fact, you could change the code so that it checks for an empty string in the property rather than setting each background.

Back to 1:

The `row` is in fact a column. The code looks at each row in the table, checking the column number for the cell that was clicked. If the background colour of the cell in that row & column is white then it's added to the `row` array. This way the last cell that's added to `row` is the first available cell in that column.

The `row` variable is redeclared each time the function is called, so it is empty each time the function is called. When a function is called all variables that are declared in it are set back to their initial values. Beware global variables, because that doesn't happen with them.

If you fill up a column with red and yellow, then click on the column again, you should get an index out of range error, because the `row` will be empty.

Comment: Matt Thank you so much for this clear reply. I've been learning about using class and how to change them with JS but only now it became clear to me the difference between class and the style object itself .